# The Projection to a Projective Line is Holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, projective-geometry, complex-manifolds

I have a line $L\subset \mathbb CP^2$ and a point $R\in \mathbb CP^2-L$. I need to prove that the map 
\begin{align*}
\varphi:\mathbb CP^2&-\{R\} \to L\\
&P\quad\mapsto L\cap L_{RP}
\end{align*}
where $L_{RP}$ is the line between $R$ and $P$, is a holomorphic map between complex manifolds.

I'm having some troubles finding an explicit description of $\varphi$, so that I can make sense of the composition with the charts. Any help? Are there other ways to prove this?

Comment: Using projective-linear transformations, you can arrange without loss of generality that, in homogeneous coordinates $(x,y,z)$, $L$ is the line $x=0$ and $R$ is the point $(1,0,0)$. Then the computation won't be so bad.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about the trasformation? Is it a change of coordinates?

Comment: The transformations that I had in mind are linear transformations of the homogeneous coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

We'll use points in the projective plane whose coordinates are ratios $(x:y:z)$Let $L$ bethe line $$\ell x+my+nz=0.$$ Let $R$ be the point $(r:s:t)$. Let $P$ be the point $(x_1:y_1:z_1).$ Then $RP$  is the line $$\ell'x+m'y+n'z=0$$ where $$[\ell',m',n']=[x_1,y_1,z_1] \mathbf x [r,s,t]$$ and $L \cap RP$ is the point whose projective coordinates are $$[\ell',m',n'] \mathbf x[\ell,m,n] $$ $$=([x_1,y_1,z_1] \mathbf x [r,s,t]) \mathbf x [\ell,m,n].$$

Comment: How is the cross product defined on the projective plane?

Comment: @LelloPold:(a:b:c:) x (d:e:f)=(bf-ce:-(af-cd):ae-bd) just the ususual way with commas replaced bby colons